# Ajax Post with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Im trying to post data to mysql by using PHP and Ajax, the only thing problem that data does not enter into database it so the problem seems in the javascript which i think ajax please help me.

Please there some one can fix it if there any error on code?

FORM:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="ajax.php" method="post">
<input name="name" id="name" type="text"/>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> 
<span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
</form>
<p id="sent-form-msg" class="success">Thanks for your comments.We will update you within 24 hours. </p>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // hide messages 
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#sent-form-msg").hide();

    // on submit...
    $("#contactForm #submit").click(function() {
        $("#error").hide();

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if(name == ""){
            $("#error").fadeIn().text("Name required.");
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if(email == ""){
            $("#error").fadeIn().text("Email required");
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            success: success()
        });
    });  

    // on success...
     function success(){
        $("#sent-form-msg").fadeIn();
        $("#contactForm").fadeOut();
     }
    return false;
});
```

AJAX.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","test");
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$sql="INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you should always escape your variables before inserting them into a database.

Comment: get rid of the form tag in your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include the URL you want to POST to in the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: dataString,
    success: success()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest doing:

HTML:

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text"/>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="validate();" id="submit" /> 
<span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
<p id="sent-form-msg" class="success">Thanks for your comments.We will update you within 24 hours. </p>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // hide messages 
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#sent-form-msg").hide();
}
    // on submit...
    function validate()
{
        $("#error").hide();

        var name = $("#name").val();
        if(name == ""){
            $("#error").fadeIn().text("Name required.");
            $("input#name").focus();
        }

        var email = $("#email").val();
        if(email == ""){
            $("#error").fadeIn().text("Email required");
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }

       // var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email;

        $.ajax({
            url: "phpScript.php"
            type:"POST",
            data: {name:name, email:email},
            success: success()
        });
    });  

    // on success...
     function success(){
        $("#sent-form-msg").fadeIn();
        $("#contactForm").fadeOut();
    }

}
```

PHP:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","test");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
//I like to do it like this:

$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

    /*if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }*/
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($con);
```

I give credit also to the other answer by mattmemo. The thing he corrected was definitely a mistake. I think there may have been other mistakes in MARGELANI's script so I chose to post my answer as well. If this script doesn't work let my know and I will recode it. Good luck! :D